# Error Exception throw by agent :java.lang.Nullpointerexception when starting spark tracker on DSE

Tags: datastax-enterprise, cassandra-2.0

I am getting Error: Exception throw by agent :java.lang.Nullpointerexception when starting spark tracker on DSE 4.5  using: dse cassandra -k

Any idea?

Comment: Can you post a full stacktrace and more context where do you see the error? Can you check what' in the system.log and post it here? There should be more details there.

Comment: Can you provide more information? The full stack trace from logs?

Answer (score 2):

I figured out the problem. If a Cassandra process is running and if you try to start it then it usually throws this error.

A few hours earlier while upgrading from Cassandra from 1.x to 2.x, I faced this issue. After killing all processes related to Cassandra, I tried to start Cassandra again and it worked.

**Example**

```
$ ps -ef | grep cassandra
root      5851  5204  0 15:34 pts/6    00:00:00 sudo cassandra -f
root      5855  5851  0 15:34 pts/6    00:00:05 java -ea -javaagent:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/jamm

$sudo kill -9 5851 5204 5855 5851 
$ sudo cassandra -f
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.